# Why do my images disappear when I add display: flex?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to add an image slider to my website using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcdBOoK3Pfw and one of the things that you need to do to create it is put the slides in a `display: flex` so that they are side by side (and then javascript is added to make it work).

In my website, the slides should be made up of an image next to some text. However, when I try to put the slides in a `display: flex` the images disappear and I am left with only text boxes next to each other. I don't know why this is happening. The exact same thing happens when I tried to use a `display: grid` instead with the number of columns = the number of slides.

How do I fix this?

```css
.slides-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 7rem;

    .slides {
        display: flex;
        // also tried this
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

        width: 100%;
    }
}

.slide {
    @include gridRepeat(2); // puts slide in display: grid with 2 columns
    border-radius: 10px;

    .img-container img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 445px;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    }

    .img-side-info {
        background-color: $light-grey;
        border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
        @include flexCenter(column); // display: flex and center everything with direction column
        align-items: flex-start;
        gap: 1rem;
        padding: 0 5rem;

        .words {
            font-size: 23.5px;
            font-weight: lighter;
            letter-spacing: 0.05px;
        }

        .name {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        a {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slides-container">
    <div class="slides">
        <!-- slide 1 -->
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="/airbnb/media/img-slider/slide-img-1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img-side-info">
                <p class="words">
                    "Hosting has been so rewarding and life-changing. It’s allowed us to pursue our passion for interior design and helped us realise our niche – that we really love renovating spaces for others to enjoy."
                </p>
                <p class="name">
                    Catherine,<br>
                    interior designer and Host in Columbus, Ohio
                </p>
                <a href="">Get host tips</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- slide 2 -->
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="/airbnb/media/img-slider/slide-img-2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img-side-info">
                <p class="words">
                    "Give yourself permission to play. I’ve poured so much love into restoring this space – and I think guests come back for that very reason."
                </p>
                <p class="name">
                     Tiffany,<br>
                     former creative director and Host in Hollywood Beach, California
                </p>
                <a href="">Get host tips</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- slide 3 -->
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="/airbnb/media/img-slider/slide-img-3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="img-side-info">
                <p class="words">
                    "The part that I love most about hosting is the design and curating the spaces for the guests – cool details and making things they can interact with. You're helping them create memories."
                </p>
                <p class="name">
                     Jordan,<br>
                     architect and Host in Denver, Colorado
                </p>
                <a href="">Visit her profile</a>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In flexbox, it's the content width that set the container width. It is the principle of flex. But a fluid image has no width so your flex container has no width too => the image doesn't appear.

So this should be fixed by setting a fixed width for your flex-item OR using fixed Gatsby Image instead.

(according to https://newbedev.com/image-disappears-when-container-becomes-flex-container-gatsby)

```
.img-container img{
    width: 555px;
    max-width: 555px;
    }
```